# No errors on SSD but it fails to boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

*I hope this question is not off-topic here. If yes, please tell me where has to be posted.*

I have a PC with this configuration:

- MSI Z77A-G45 (MS-7752)
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- 4x DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns) 4 GB each
- GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] using `nvidia-driver-470` from `metapackage`
- 2x SSD 256 GB Samsung 830 Series
- Ubuntu 22.04

Since a couple of weeks, very often on power up it fails to complete the loading of the OS:

[image]

Trying to continue leads to this error:

[image]

The only way I found to continue to work is:

1. run a Linux live (i.e. Clonezilla)
2. run `fsck` on all the drives
3. reboot

Usually it works, even it requires a couple of this procedure. But after some reboots it fails again.

The first thought it was I have a faulty SSD, but the Ubuntu disk manager it says all the drivers are "ok", and also the output of `fsck` seems error free:

[image]

Because this is the PC I use for my job I need to understand where is the problem and how to fix it.

**Is this odd behavior a symptom of an SSD with errors or damaged?
Is there a chance to fix it or I have to buy another one and install everything again?**

### UPDATE

Here some relevant extract from the log file retrieve with `journalctl -xb` when the issue was present. I can post the whole file but it's quite long:

```
$ grep -i "warning" log.txt 
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20210730/utaddress-204)
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab apparmor.systemd[987]: Warning: found usr.sbin.sssd in /etc/apparmor.d/force-complain, forcing complain mode
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab apparmor.systemd[987]: Warning from /etc/apparmor.d (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sssd line 60): Caching disabled for: 'usr.sbin.sssd' due to force complain

$ grep -i "error" log.txt 
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform retains control of PCIe features (AE_ERROR)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
lug 23 08:48:01 ulab kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.

$ grep -i "fail" log.txt 
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
lug 23 08:48:02 ulab systemd-udevd[440]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:02 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:02 ulab systemd-udevd[423]: sr0: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sr0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: sda1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda1' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[425]: sdb1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb1' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[442]: sdc: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[429]: sdb2: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb2' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[435]: 3-4.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3 189:259' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[435]: 3-4.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3 189:259' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[433]: 3-4.4: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.4 189:260' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[433]: 3-4.4: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.4 189:260' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.6:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.6:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.6: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6 189:261' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.6: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6 189:261' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[423]: 3-4.6.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.2 189:263' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[423]: 3-4.6.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.2 189:263' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.6.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.1 189:262' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.6.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.1 189:262' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[421]: 3-4.6.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.3 189:264' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[421]: 3-4.6.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.3 189:264' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[421]: 3-4.6.3:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.3/3-4.6.3:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[421]: 3-4.6.3:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.3/3-4.6.3:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[421]: 3-4.6.3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.3/3-4.6.3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[421]: 3-4.6.3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.3/3-4.6.3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[437]: 3-4.1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.4:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.4/3-4.4:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[437]: 3-4.1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[444]: 3-4.4:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.4/3-4.4:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[425]: 3-4.3:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3/3-4.3:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[425]: 3-4.3:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3/3-4.3:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[423]: 3-4.6.2:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.2/3-4.6.2:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[431]: 3-4.3:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3/3-4.3:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[431]: 3-4.3:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3/3-4.3:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[433]: 3-4.3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3/3-4.3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[429]: 3-4.4:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.4/3-4.4:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[423]: 3-4.6.2:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.2/3-4.6.2:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[429]: 3-4.4:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.4/3-4.4:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[443]: 3-4.6.1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.1/3-4.6.1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[443]: 3-4.6.1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.6/3-4.6.1/3-4.6.1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:03 ulab systemd-udevd[433]: 3-4.3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4.3/3-4.3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
lug 23 08:48:04 ulab systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
░░ Unità modprobe@efi_pstore.service entrata nello stato 'failed' (fallito) con risultato 'start-limit-hit'.
lug 23 08:48:04 ulab systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
░░ Il risultato è failed.
lug 23 08:48:04 ulab systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_blk.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
░░ Unità modprobe@pstore_blk.service entrata nello stato 'failed' (fallito) con risultato 'start-limit-hit'.
lug 23 08:48:04 ulab systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Module pstore_blk.
░░ Il risultato è failed.
lug 23 08:48:04 ulab systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_zone.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
░░ Unità modprobe@pstore_zone.service entrata nello stato 'failed' (fallito) con risultato 'start-limit-hit'.
lug 23 08:48:04 ulab systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Module pstore_zone.
░░ Il risultato è failed.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/dev.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: mnt-dev.mount: Job mnt-dev.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d601fe13-dc29-45a3-b49d-b2eb57ebe89f.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d601fe13\x2ddc29\x2d45a3\x2db49d\x2db2eb57ebe89f.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d601fe13\x2ddc29\x2d45a3\x2db49d\x2db2eb57ebe89f.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
lug 23 08:49:31 ulab systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d601fe13\x2ddc29\x2d45a3\x2db49d\x2db2eb57ebe89f.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d601fe13\x2ddc29\x2d45a3\x2db49d\x2db2eb57ebe89f.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Of course I see a lot of bad messages here but I cannot understand the root cause.

### UPDATE 2

Here the SMART attributes:

```
$ sudo smartctl --all -d ata /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series
Serial Number:    S0VZNEAC705496
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 043584d30
Firmware Version: CXM03B1Q
User Capacity:    256.060.514.304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 2
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jul 25 18:36:27 2022 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  25) The self-test routine was aborted by
                    the host.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 1020) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  17) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       23782
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       6504
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       84
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   060   034   000    Old_age   Always       -       40
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       90
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       8131266591

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23686         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     23686         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               60%     23686         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: What do you have in the system log? Better also check the SMART status of the SSD.

Comment: so, assuming this is *not* your SSD seems natural. Did you do what the prompt recommends, run `journalctl -xb` and inspect the output?

Comment: @harrymc the SMART feature is enabled, if you was suggesting this. Otherwise, please clarify what I need to check

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've just update the question with some outputs from that log file

Comment: I suggested to check the SMART attributes of the disk for errors. If unsure, you could add the screenshot to your post.

Comment: @harrymc please, could you check if this is the correct output you need?

Comment: Yes - your disk is in perfect state. We can conclude that this is not a hardware error.

Comment: @harrymc glad to know this. Now how should I go ahead to fix the error? Is there a more suitable website where to ask help?

Comment: While booting, do you ever a Fail message? Try also [this advice](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/1910611/comments/2).

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar setup

- MSI Z77A-G43 (MS-7758)
- Intel i7-3770 @ 3.40GHz
- 2x4GB DIMM DDR3 2133MHz
- NVIDIA GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti]
- 2x500GB Samsung 840 SSD
- Ubuntu 22.04

I got the same problem a while back. Unfortunately I can't remember exactly how I fixed it but since we have such similar hardware I thought Id write down what I do remember and hopefully it helps.
I think the issue for me was that I had made an error in fstab on top of not setting 'nofail' to a none crucial partition making my system believe it could not boot without that drive though it was just filled with pictures.

But you write that your machine only fails to boot sometimes. Does the available hardware change often? For example an USB-hub gets connected halve the times or a network drive not always being available?
Do you have Windows installed on any common drive? I do and I had some issue mounting a drive whenever I choose "reboot" and then shut the computer down from UEFI rather than using the "shut down" option.

I AM sure that the ACPI Error is not at fault here anyway. I get that too and though it is incredibly annoying to see, it's harmless.

Good luck, and any questions at all, just ask, I love to help out with what I can though still being a somewhat n00b my self. I have only been using Linux for two years.